# Построчное сравнение значения из столбца. Часть 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Имеем код. В нем построчно сравниваем, удовлетворяет ли условию > или < движение цены в следующих строках, после открытия на уровне Open.

Нужно ответить на вопрос (записал как print).
1. Какое значение имела цена, в момент Open первого дня (в нашем случае это 115.8 - как получить?).
2. Если первым сработал df.Low < df.Open * (1 - d), то написать его ответ (для 0,05% это 115.8*0.995 = 115.22). Если сработал df.High > df.Open * (1 + d), то записать в ответ это значение (115.8*1.005 = 116.378 - в нашем случае не сработал в первой строке, а в следующих его считать уже не надо, т.к. зафиксировали значение Low, поэтому не пишем). Если ни то не другое - записать в ответ значение Close последней строки (у нас будет так, если например d = 1 (10%), тогда нужно взять цену закрытия последнего дня - пишем 119.11).

```css
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime 

df = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-10')

d = 0.005  # 0.5%

df['new'] = \
np.where(
    df.Low < df.Open * (1 - d),
    df.Low,
    np.where(df.High > df.Open * (1 + d),
        df.High,
        np.nan
    )
)


print( ) # Open price
print( ) # Equity
```

Comment: Вы можете привести пример данных (3-5 строк со след. столбцами: `['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']`) и пример ожидаемого результата - все это в текстовом виде? Данные можно округлить для простоты понимания.

Comment: я привел пример __данных__ в вашем вопросе. Можете на основе данного примера (его можно сократить, например до 3х строк) привести пример того, что вы ожидаете __в виде данных (строк)__

Comment: честно говоря, мне пока не очень понятно... Я думаю было бы гораздо проще понять ваше текстовое описание если бы вы показали пример выходных (результирующих) данных - например в виде DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]:
                  Open        High         Low       Close    Volume   Adj Close
Date
2017-01-03  115.800003  116.330002  114.760002  116.150002  28781900  115.648597
2017-01-04  115.849998  116.510002  115.750000  116.019997  21118100  115.519154
2017-01-05  115.919998  116.860001  115.809998  116.610001  22193600  116.106611
2017-01-06  116.779999  118.160004  116.470001  117.910004  31751900  117.401002
2017-01-09  117.949997  119.430000  117.940002  118.989998  33387600  118.476334
2017-01-10  118.769997  119.379997  118.300003  119.110001  24462100  118.595819
```

> как узнать чему равно `df.Open` от 2017-01-01

```
In [79]: df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Open')]
Out[79]: 115.800003
```

> как узнать, чему равно `Close` от 2017-01-10

```
In [80]: df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Close')]
Out[80]: 119.110001



In [13]: d = 0.05

In [14]: df['rslt'] = \
    ...:     np.where(
    ...:         df.Low < df.Open * (1 - d),
    ...:         df.Open * (1 - d),
    ...:         np.where(df.High > df.Open * (1 + d),
    ...:             df.Open * (1 + d),
    ...:             df.Close
    ...:         )
    ...:     )
    ...:

    In [15]: df
    Out[15]:
                      Open        High         Low       Close    Volume   Adj Close        rslt
    Date
    2017-01-03  115.800003  116.330002  114.760002  116.150002  28781900  115.648597  116.150002
    2017-01-04  115.849998  116.510002  115.750000  116.019997  21118100  115.519154  116.019997
    2017-01-05  115.919998  116.860001  115.809998  116.610001  22193600  116.106611  116.610001
    2017-01-06  116.779999  118.160004  116.470001  117.910004  31751900  117.401002  117.910004
    2017-01-09  117.949997  119.430000  117.940002  118.989998  33387600  118.476334  118.989998
    2017-01-10  118.769997  119.379997  118.300003  119.110001  24462100  118.595819  119.110001
```

Comment: @nabafew, пардон, я не понимаю что значит `"написать, что df.total = 2, а если не для того, не для другого - 3"` - куда написать? Именно поэтому я всегда предлагаю тем кто спрашивает указывать в вопросе ожидаемый набор данных (data set)

Comment: `Что такое ожидаемый набор данных?` - предположим вы хотите получить в результате объект в переменной `result` типа/вида - DataFrame/Series/что-то еще. Все что я прошу это предполагаемый вывод команды: `print(result)` - т.е. набор ожидаемый набор данных

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54426/discussion-between-maxu-and-nabafew).